# Question about possibilities of a team

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

consider an experiment that consists of determining the type of job - either blue-collar or white collar- and the political affiliation -republicans, democratic or independent - of the 15 members of an adult soccer team. how many outcomes are in the sample space?

I calculated it by doing the following calculation:

15x2x3=90 outcomes

However the answer is 6^15. How did they calculate it like this and why is my calculation wrong?

Comment: Could you explain how you got to $15 \times 2 \times 3$?

Comment: Yes, I had 15 people, and for each 15 I had two possibilities for their occupations being either blue collar or white collar, and then three possibilities for their political affiliations. So I multiplied the possibilities and came up with 15x2x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for every player, the total number of pairings (job,political affiliation) are $\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{3}{1} = 6$. Assuming that pairings of any 2 soccer players are independent, each player has 6 options of the pairings. thus it would be $ \underbrace{6 \times 6 \times 6 \cdots 6}_{\textrm{15 times}} = 6^{15}$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now how they arrived at this calculation. However, I am still not sure why the calculation I derived was incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [basic counting principle of multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), it must be $2^{15}\times 3^{15}=6^{15}$.

Comment: Thanks this makes it clear how it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

$ \underbrace{6 \times 6 \times 6 \cdots 6}_{\textrm{15 times}} = 6^{15}$

This is because of the fundamental principle of product that states that if a job is doable in $m$ ways and another job is doable in $n$ ways, the number of ways in which both the jobs are doable is $m\times n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are $6$ choices in each of the $15$ cases, it is $6^{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an application of the basic principle of counting.

$$2^{15}\times 3^{15}=6^{15}$$